# Correct way to handle jqGrid ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jqgrid

Instead of just "hard-coding" the url in the jqGrid definition, I want to have my own function that does the AJAX call.

I've tried a couple of options but none truly mimics the scenario when we have the url directly applied.

Basically what I need is to keep all the default behavior of jqGrid but being me the one responsible for doing the ajax call the the server.

```
var loadData = function () {
    var formData = $('#formFilters').serializeArray();

    getData(formData)
        .then(function (data) {
            $grid
                .setGridParam({ "datatype": "jsonstring", "datastr": data })
                .trigger("reloadGrid");

            resizeGrid();
    })
};
```

And the grid is plugged like:

```
$grid.jqGrid({
    datatype: loadData,
    colModel: [...]
```

The main problem here is that the sorting won't trigger the ajax call and I'm afraid I need to hack this a bit more.

Is there a best-practice on how to achieve this decoupling between the grid and the data service function?

Thanks,
Alex

Comment: Could you explain what you mean under "hard-coding" the url in the jqGrid definition, and want kind of "your own function" you need? If you would write an example then I would show which jqGrid parameters can be used. Probably you need just use `loadonce: true`  option in combination with `postData`.

Comment: Hi Oleg, so the normal usage is to use the url property of the grid and the ajax call will be done internally. The thing is that in this proj I can't call directly a server-side service that understands the jqGrid postData structure. So what I have is my own function that takes the postData info and performs the ajax call in the way it's understandable by the server. The issue now is that doing it the way I'm doing it, the grid behaves like it's local data.

Comment: @Sorry, but you posted no code or no exact example what you do. jqGrid have a lot of possibility to use dynamic url parameters and to make any kind of serialization. **If you post the example** of what you do I would show how to convert the code to the code which use `datatype: "json"` and other options which full customize the Ajax call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can hook into this event:

jqGridSortCol

it is documented here: http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:events

You can try to first get current filters object like this:

```
var f = 'gridselector'
var flts = $( '#' + f ).jqGrid('getGridParam', 'postData').filters
```

you can alter that object, and than on the hooked event try something like this:

```
$( '#' + f ).jqGrid( 'setGridParam', { search: true, postData: flts } ); 
$( '#' + f ).jqGrid().trigger('reloadGrid');
```

ps.. maybe you could do some jsfiddle out of your problem so we can take a look more deeply :)

Comment: It's exactly this kind of hacky stuff I wanted to avoid.
Ideally I want to keep all the default functionality of the grid but handle the ajax call my self. The reason is mainly because I don't fully control the server, and I need to work with what I have.
Another reason is more of design, trying to decouple the UI configuration from the methods that actually perform the backend calls.

Comment: I gave you link for official jqgrid documentation and how to use it on event that you needed, and that is column sorting as you said.. it is no hacky stuff!

Comment: I ended up going through this path and it works well. When I said hack is just because I was hopping that the grid could trigger the refresh automatically. Thanks!